# How to export Class(not Component) from Angular Library(package)

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-library

Ive tried several answer here but none worked for me.
Im trying to export Class from library and use it on my other app.
but when I try doing it I get this error:

> ROR TypeError:
>   marvilix_header__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.RoutingHeader is not a
>   constructor

my code: routing-class.ts

```
export class RoutingHeader{

    public itsActive: boolean;
    public Name: string;
    public Button: boolean;
    public Route: string;
    public links: Array<RoutingHeader>;

    constructor(name:string,button:boolean,route:string,links:Array<RoutingHeader>){
        this.Name = name;
        this.Button = button;
        this.Route = route;
        this.links = links;
        this.itsActive = false;
    }

}
```

public_api.ts

```
export * from './lib/marvilix-header.service';
export * from './lib/marvilix-header.component';
export * from './lib/marvilix-header.module';
export * from './lib/routing-class';
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RoutingHeader } from 'marvilix-header';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public links:Array<RoutingHeader>;
  constructor(){
   this.links = [
     new RoutingHeader("s",false,"s",null)
   ] 
  }
}
```

any thoughts?
Tnx in advance!

Comment: I think what you're trying to use this as is a Datamodel. If that's really the case, Angular recommends the use of `interface` instead of a `class`. That being said, can you please try changing the class to an interface and check to see if that works for you?

Comment: In interface you dont have constructor, I need constructor.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to understand here, actually, but fail to. Can you please explain why exactly do you need it? Interfaces are used in Angular to describe the data model of a variable. From the OP, I'm not able to find any specific use-case why a component MUST be used.

Comment: @SiddAjmera can you or cant you use export class from library?

Comment: Need to see the code, tried to reproduce on my machine, there's no issue in exporting class, everything works (cannot reproduce)

Comment: @AkshayRajput try to use npm i marvilix-header
and tell me if you can use the RoutingHeader class constrator

Comment: sure checking give me 5 mins

Comment: @AlexLeibovich Tested the package its working, I am able to import the class in the project

Comment: @AkshayRajput and you manage to use constructor?

Comment: @AlexLeibovich yeah, created a stackblitz for demo as well,  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dq9epd